# chaining functions with a function argument

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is 'connect' an array of functions together with a function. So in an array of functions:

```
var functionArray = [functionA, functionB, functionC];
```

`functionA(next)` should be able to invoke a call to its function argument `next` to call `functionB`.

The problem is that I cannot use promises (it would make it a lot easier, unfortunate), so I devised a way like this:

```
var functionArray = [functionA, functionB];

functionArray.push(functionC.bind(undefined, args));

for (var i = functionArray.length - 1; i-- > 0; ) {
  functionArray[i] = functionArray[i].bind(undefined, args, functionArray[i + 1]);
}

functionArray[0]();
```

My question is whether or not there is a better way to accomplish this, as the above function looks terribly hacky. Maybe something with *Array.prototype.reduce*?

Comment: Could you describe the problem you're trying to solve; meaning, for what problem is this the solution? Why can't you use promises? I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking or what you want to achieve. Is the result of functionA an argument of functionB  or is functionB called from the scope of functionA?

Comment: It's supposed to allow functions to asynchronously link to one another, so ultimately I want to have a function that turns an array into functions that can do this;

`function functionA(next) {
      // dosomething
      next(); // calls functionB, no values passed, simply execution
    }
    
    function functionB(next) {
      // dosomethingelse
      next(); // calls functionC and so on...
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a multidimensional array to store the function and it's arguments. This can be cleaned up some but the basic idea is this:

```
var functionArray = [
    { func: yourFunction, args: [1, 2] }
];

for (var i = 0 i < functionArray.length; i++) {
    var func = functionArray[i].func;
    var args = functionArray[i].args;
    func.apply(this, args);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding your question fully but it sounds like you are wanting to store functions "and" their arguments to call them later.

Comment: I will actually accept this answer as the use of `apply` is rather useful in this case, considering I can also pass the next function in the chain as an argument. Thanks!